# D3JS line chart inverted issue

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, linechart

Am trying to **dynamically produce** line charts depending on the JSON data inputted:

Here's my **JS** code:

```
d3.json("../js/sample2.json", function(data) {
    var dataArray = new Array(), k = 0, j = 0, dataArraySize = 0, line, positionNumber,
            canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1000)
            .attr("height", 1000)
            .attr("border", "black")

    heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 250])
            .range([300, 0]);

    widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 200])
            .range([0, 700]);

    Yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .ticks(5)
            .scale(heightScale)
            .orient("left");

    Xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .ticks(10)
            .scale(widthScale)
            .orient("bottom");

    jsonLength = Object.keys(data).length;

    group = canvas.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grp")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100,10)");

//    Conversion of JSON data to appropriate data format
    for (j = 0; j < jsonLength; j += 2) {
        var innerObjArray = new Array();
        positionNumber = Object.keys(data[j].position).length;
        for (k = 0; k < positionNumber; k++) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.x = data[j].position[k];
            obj.y = data[j + 1].position[k];
            innerObjArray.push(obj);
        }
        dataArray.push(innerObjArray);
    }
    console.log(dataArray);
    dataArraySize = dataArray.length;

//Graphical representation of the dataArray
    line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
    for (k = 0; k < dataArraySize; k++) {
        d3.select(".grp")
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", line(dataArray[k]))
                // .attr("transform", "translate(100,10)")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",50%,50%)")
                .attr("stroke-width", 3);
        console.log(dataArray[k]);
    }

    group.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, 300 )")
            .call(Xaxis)


    group.append("g")
            .call(Yaxis)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
});
```

I have given

```
 heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 250])
        .range([300, 0]);
```

Which i thought would work,but it didnt.

Here's my **JSON data**:

```
     [{"name": "x1", 
  "position":[0,60,80,100,200]
 },

 {"name": "y1", 
  "position":[0,190,220,160,240]
  },

 {"name": "x2", 
  "position":[0,60,80,100,200]
 },

 {"name": "y2", 
  "position":[10,90,20,60,40]},

 {"name": "x3", 
  "position":[30,50,70,90,150]
 },

 {"name": "y3", 
  "position":[20,160,170,160,150]}]
```

**This is currently my output**
[image: This is currently my output]

Right now the chart is starting from the (200,240) position..

The chart is currently inverted as i have started the line at (0,0) ending at (200,240) for the 1st line and so forth..(Inputted through the JSON data)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include what you are expecting? It is not clear.

Comment: Updated,the json data that is inputted has been graphically represented,but the graph is inverted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to use the scales you have defined so items are been plotted using the svg coordinate system (which starts in the top left corner as (0,0).

So when defining the line use `return widthScale(d.x)` instead of just `return d.x` and so forth

```
line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return widthScale(d.x);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return heightScale(d.y);
        });
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q5r2/) for what I think is you are expecting.

[image: Fixed chart]